# 95% confidence intervals in matlab for a summed gaussian

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian, confidence-interval

I have fit some data in the curve fitting toolbox in Matlab using a fit comprised of 2 summed Gaussians. Matlab was able to plot the upper and lower 95% confidence intervals for me very nicely.

Now, I have some new data that fits best to a curve that is comprised of 3 Gaussians, but the toolbox won't plot the 95% CI in this case. It returns NaN at all points along the curve, rather than numerical values for the 95% CIs.

Here is some of the code:

```
X = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Y = [0.009 0.014 0.031 0.044 0.062 0.065 0.052 0.037 0.037 0.027 0.026]';
STDV = [0.0028 0.0013 0.0047 0.00356 0.0077 0.0141 0.0072 0.0055 0.0055 0.0040 0.0055]';

[a1,b1,c1] = deal(0.036, 4.34, 2.02);
[a2,b2,c2] = deal(0.034, 6.78, 6.02);

fo1 = fitoptions('method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[-Inf -Inf 0]);
ok1 = isfinite(X) & isfinite(Y);
if ~all( ok1 )
    warning( 'GenerateMFile:IgnoringNansAndInfs',...
        'Ignoring NaNs and Infs in data.' );
end
st1 = [a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2];
set(fo1,'Startpoint',st1);
ft1 = fittype('gauss2');

% Fit this model using new data
cf1 = fit(X(ok1),Y(ok1),ft1,fo1);
% Plot this fit and the calculated dose points
h1 = plot(cf1,'fit',0.95);
set(h1(1),'Color',[0 0 0],...
    'LineStyle','-', 'LineWidth',1,...
    'Marker','none', 'MarkerSize',6);
hold on;
errorbar(X,Y,STDV,'*k')


%Break dose range into many intervals
Dose_range = 0:0.01:10;
%Plot confidence interval fits
load('ratio_lower.mat');
load('ratio_upper.mat');
plot(Dose_range,ratio_lower,'k:');
plot(Dose_range,ratio_upper,'k:');
```

The 'ratio_lower' and 'ratio_upper' are the CIs that are generated from the analysis GUI in cftool. It works nicely for 2 summed Gaussians, but not for 3 summed Gaussians.

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: There isn't much code to show since I use the

Comment: curve fitting tool. I'll try to put something here though....sorry about the multiple posting

Comment: Even a description of what you did that led up to the problem that you're experiencing now is good.  Try even sharing some data too.  We can't really reproduce your problem here.

Comment: X = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Y = [0.009 0.014 0.031 0.044 0.062 0.065 0.052 0.037 0.037 0.027 0.026]';
STDV = [0.0028 0.0013 0.0047 0.00356 0.0077 0.0141 0.0072 0.0055 0.0055 0.0040 0.0055]';

[a1,b1,c1] = deal(0.036, 4.34, 2.02);
[a2,b2,c2] = deal(0.034, 6.78, 6.02);
st1 = [a1 b1 c1 a2 b2 c2];
ft1 = fittype('gauss2');

errorbar(X,Y,STDV,'*k')
hold on;

%Break dose range into many intervals
Dose_range = 0:0.01:10;
%Plot confidence interval fits
load('ratio_lower.mat');
load('ratio_upper.mat');
plot(Dose_range,ratio_lower,'k:');
plot(Dose_range,ratio_upper,'k:');

Comment: Sorry....stupid enter button! OK, so that's the basic code of what I'm trying to plot. The ratio_upper and ratio_lower files are the 95% CI generated from the cftool, then I plot everything as part of a bigger code. The issue now is that my fit is a sum of 3 gaussians and the cftool won't plot the 95% confidence intervals....im not a matlab guru, and the cftool is awesome...maybe the fit is too complicated for it to generate the intervals? I appreciate your trying to help me out :)

Comment: Please edit your original post with this code.  It's really ugly to read long lines of code in a comment box.

Comment: OK I've made some edits...still learning this website also. There is some code there, most of it is just generated from cftool, so you can at least see what I'm doing.